# Как можно использовать filter в этом стриме?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, java-stream

Как использовать в stream api, которое используется в этом методе конвейерный метод filter, насколько я понял он должен быть использован вместо foreeach, подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать?

```
public void expiredDate() throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();


    String startDate = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
    //String endDate = "30.01.2021";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");

    Date start = sdf.parse(startDate);
    Parser p = new Parser();

    AtomicInteger reuslt = new AtomicInteger(0);
    p.parseJson().stream()
            .map(elem -> {
                System.out.println("Компании " + elem.getOrgName() + " принадлежат бумаги с истёкшим сроком");
                return elem.getSecurities();
            })
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .forEach(elem -> {
                try {
                    if (sdf.parse(elem.getTimeEnd()).before(start)) {
                        reuslt.getAndIncrement();
                        System.out.println("Название " + elem.getName() + " Код " + elem.getCode() + " Дата истечения "
                                + elem.getTimeEnd());
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    System.out.println("Всего просроченных ценных бумаг " + reuslt);
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, а почему вы решили, что вам filter подойдёт? У filter суть следующая - он как бы фильтрует стрим, выкидывая некоторые элементы, которые на следующий шаг не переходят. Форич это терминальная операция, то есть завершающая, после неё ничего делать нельзя. А filter - промежуточная операция (вроде так называется), так что не вполне понятно, как вы хотите заменить их

Comment: Как бы в чистом виде foreach и filter невзаимозаменимы. foreach всегда последний, после него ничего нельзя сделать. А filter наооборот - всегда требует, чтобы после него было что-то ещё.

Comment: @Zhenyria, видимо я просто ошибся, если они не взаимозаменяемы, то как просто переписать этот метод с использование filter?
А решил я его здесь использовать потому что у меня такие условия задачи )

Comment: Тогда просто условие убирание из for each и впихивает в filter

Comment: @AzizUmarov спасибо, получилось!

Comment: @ule если ответ ниже решил ваш вопрос, отметьте его решением.

Comment: @AzizUmarov помоги пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1239473/427834

Comment: @Zhenyria помоги пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1239473/427834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будет как то так

```
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .filter(elem -> sdf.parse(elem.getTimeEnd()).before(start))
        .forEach(elem -> {
            try {
                    reuslt.getAndIncrement();
                    System.out.println("Название " + elem.getName() + " Код " + elem.getCode() + " Дата истечения "
                            + elem.getTimeEnd());
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```