# Как переписать цикл foreeach на стрим апи с использованием filter?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, java-stream

Как переписать цикл foreeach в этом методе на стрим апи с использованием filter?

```
public void checkDateOrg(String date)  {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");

    Date datte = null;

    if(date.contains("/")) {
        try {
            datte = sdf1.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else {
        try {
            datte = sdf.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Date dFn = null;
    Parser p = new Parser();
    for (Params elem : p.parseJson()) {
        try {
            dFn = sdf1.parse(elem.getDateOfFoundation());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (datte.before(dFn)) {
            System.out.println(elem.getOrgName() + " Основан после " + date);
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: что такое щя посмотрим

Comment: @AzizUmarov проблема в том, что в этом fore each цикле есть переменная dFn = sdf1.parse(elem.getDateOfFoundation()); и когда я пытаюсь с ней работать в стримах и лямбдах java мне говорит, что она должна быть либо атомарной либо нужно её обработать через массив, но когда я это делаю ни так ни так у меня не работает код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

будет как-то так

```
p.parseJson().stream().filter(elem=> {
     SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy"); 
    try {
        Date dFn = sdf1.parse(elem.getDateOfFoundation());
        return datte.before(dFn); 
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false; 
    }
}).forEach(....
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Код заработал, теперь дело за малым - понять как он заработал и что происходит )

Comment: Не вопрос пользуйся